# Copied table formatting

Tags: javascript

I have a simple HTML table which I'd like to copy to the clipboard. So far it works.

The only problem is that the table's formatting does not get copied as well. Is there a simple solution? I can only find answers to copied text.

My Code:

```js
function CopyTable(tableId) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("tableId");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    copyText.style.border = "1px solid black";
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText);
}
```

```html
<table id = "tableId">
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>Test2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button class="button" onclick="CopyTable()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'table's formatting' ?

Comment: I mean borders, column's colors, etc. The current output is [object HTMLTableElement] instead of the real cell's text.

Comment: You can't convert borders, colors etc into copyable text? Not sure what you expect to be put into your clipboard.

Comment: Firstly, I tried to create an "open in word/pdf" button. But for reasons, this will not work. The "copy the whole table including formatting etc." was then my second thought, because the user would just need to CTRL + V.

Comment: You should be able to do something like this by using `navigator.clipboard.write()` with an HTML string and a `text/html` MIME type, but it has a pretty bad browser support as of now...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `copyText.textContent`

```js
function CopyTable(array, tableId, tableDiv) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("tableId");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    copyText.style.border = "1px solid black";
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.textContent);
}
```

```html
<table id = "tableId">
<tr>
  <td>Test</td>
  <td>Test2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button class="button" onclick="CopyTable()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: And yet, when pasted (Firefox 105, Ubuntu 22.04), it simply pastes "[object HTMLTableElement]"

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. However, it prints Test and Test2 in two separate rows. I'd like to copy the exact formatting (e.g. Test and Test2 in 2 columns, but one row).